# How to prevent WIFI dongle from turning off when switching OSes?

Tags: wifi, usb

I'm using both Windows10 and Fedora on my system. Windows boots as the default OS and I have no problem with my WIFI dongle on windows. But when I want to use Fedora, I have to boot manually; when it comes up, the WIFI dongle is off; so I have to take the dongle out and put it in every time I use Fedora. Is there any settings to keep it on? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

No. The "WiFi is up" status is kept partially on the card and partially in the OS. When you switch OSes, you lose the lattter.

If Fedora has `nmcli`, you could `nmcli con up id foo` (if your ESSID is `foo`).

You should be able to configure Fedora to auto start the WiFi interface.